# Find and replace missing values with row mean

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, mean

I have a data frame with NAs and I want to replace the NAs with row means

```
c1 = c(1,2,3,NA)
c2 = c(3,1,NA,3)
c3 = c(2,1,3,1)

df = data.frame(c1,c2,c3)

> df
  c1 c2 c3
1  1  3  2
2  2  1  1
3  3 NA  3
4 NA  3  1
```

so that

```
> df
  c1 c2 c3
1  1  3  2
2  2  1  1
3  3  3  3
4  2  3  1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very similar to @baptiste's answer

```
> ind <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
> df[ind] <- rowMeans(df,  na.rm = TRUE)[ind[,1]]
```

Comment: I found if I have whole rows of NAs, an error occurs. Is it proper etiquette to pose this as a whole new question?

Answer (score 4):

I think this works,

```
df[which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)] <- rowMeans(df[!complete.cases(df), ], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: it's a bit redundant to use both is.na and complete.cases ; there's probably more a more efficient way in two lines

Comment: Like this perhaps? `idx <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE); df[ idx ] <- rowMeans( df[ idx[,1] , ], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @SimonO101 Jiber beat us to it

Comment: Ha ha, yeah I just saw!

Comment: I'm leaving this one for the sake of variety; also, the `complete.cases` part might be useful in a different situation

Answer (score 3):

Using `apply` (note the returned object is a `matrix`):

```
t( apply( df , 1 , function(x) { x[ is.na(x) ] = mean( x , na.rm = TRUE ); x } ) )
     c1 c2 c3
[1,]  1  3  2
[2,]  2  1  1
[3,]  3  3  3
[4,]  2  3  1
```

We use any anonymous function to change the values of each `NA` in each row to the `mean` of that row. The only advantage is that you don't have to do any more typing if the number of rows increases. It is not particularly efficient or fast in a computational sense, but more so in a cognitive sense (you won't notice unless you have 000,000's of rows).

Answer (score 2):

My solution is

```
rwmns = rowMeans(df,na.rm=TRUE)
df$c1[is.na(df$c1)] = rwmns[is.na(df$c1)]
df$c2[is.na(df$c2)] = rwmns[is.na(df$c2)]
df$c3[is.na(df$c3)] = rwmns[is.na(df$c3)]
> df
  c1 c2 c3
1  1  3  2
2  2  1  1
3  3  3  3
4  2  3  1
```

Is there a more elegant way, especially when someone has many columns?

Comment: Great work coming up with your own solution.  You can use `[[` to index instead, so each line becomes `df[[col_name]][is.na(df[[col_name]])] <- rwmns[is.na(df[[col_name]])`.  That way, you can loop or use an apply family over the column names you want to perform replacement on.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `na.aggregate` from `library(zoo)` after transposing the dataset

```
library(zoo)
df[] <- t(na.aggregate(t(df)))
df
#  c1 c2 c3
#1  1  3  2
#2  2  1  1
#3  3  3  3
#4  2  3  1
```