# How to replace the missing with the mean of previous and following measures

Tags: r, multiple-columns, mean

I have a dataset with 5 columns where each column is a measure. Im trying to replace those NA with the mean of previous and following value but no luck till now. I searched and I found a solution how to replace NA with mean of row, which can't be applied here. Any help will be appreciated. I hope this thread will help others as well.

```
  A  B  C  D  E
 NA  7 NA  6  2
  4 NA  2  6 NA
  2  1 NA NA  5
```

Desired output

```
A B C D E
6.5 7 6.5 6 2
4 3 2 6 4
2 1 2 2 5
```

In the first row 6.5 comes from the mean of 7 and 6, in the second row 3 comes from mean of 4 and 2, and 4 from the mean 2 and 6. In the third row the 2 comes from the mean of 1 and 5.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @n8sty i think will be correct if i replace with mean of previous and following or in case that previous is missing with 2 following measures. Output should be: `6.5 7 6.5 6 2`

Comment: add your desired output to your question and explain how you got to it. Where does the the first 6.5 come from?

Comment: @n8sty just added with explanation. Hope is clear now. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense how the endpoint `NA` values are calculated, compared to the middle `NA` calculations.  What is there are more columns?

Comment: @Richard-Scriven yes there will be other columns. No chance to make it?

Comment: @user3872487 i think your only hope is to try and do something with logical conditioning and `zoo::na.locf'. You want to the calculation to act one way if you're on the edge of the table/matrix and differently if you're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the following require this setup:

```
library(zoo)
m <- matrix(c(NA, 4L, 2L, 7L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 6L, 6L, NA, 2L, NA, 5L), 3) # input
```

**1)** I think it would be better to extend the values on the ends so with this change try the following:

```
tm <- t(m)
mid <- (na.locf(tm) + na.locf(tm, fromLast = TRUE))/2
t(na.fill(mid, c("extend", NA)))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    7    7  6.5    6    2
[2,]    4    3  2.0    6    6
[3,]    2    1  3.0    3    5
```

By the way, note that the average of 1 and 5 is 3, not 2.

**2)** This is not equivalent but it may be what you really want and is short.  Try linear interpoolation extending the end values:

```
t(na.approx(t(m), rule = 2))
```

giving:

```
    [,1] [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,]    7    7 6.500000 6.000000    2
[2,]    4    3 2.000000 6.000000    6
[3,]    2    1 2.333333 3.666667    5
```

**3)** Another possibility, again not equivalent is to replace each NA with the mean of the non-NAs on that row:

```
t(na.aggregate(t(m)))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    7 5.000000 6.000000    2
[2,]    4    4 2.000000 6.000000    4
[3,]    2    1 2.666667 2.666667    5
```

**4)** This is a mix of (1) and (3).  This fills in inner NAs with the mean of the non-NAs to either
side and fills in the end NAs with the mean of the non-NAs in that row:

```
tm <- t(m)
mid <- (na.locf(tm) + na.locf(tm, fromLast = TRUE))/2
ag <- na.aggregate(tm)
t(ifelse(is.na(mid), ag, mid))
```

giving:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    7  6.5    6    2
[2,]    4    3  2.0    6    4
[3,]    2    1  3.0    3    5
```

**Update** Added more approaches and some correcetions.

Comment: this is what I was looking for `t(na.approx(t(m), rule = 2))`, but in my data frame i have ID variable which is numeric. How i can exclude it from the calculations?

Comment: To exclude the first column, say, from the calculation but just keep it intact try `m[, -1] <- t(na.approx(t(m[, -1]), rule = 2))` .

Comment: I did something like that `df = as.data.frame(t(na.approx(t(df[6:10]), rule = 2)))
df = merge(df, dt, by="row.names")` but can be shorter!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best/simple way to answer my question is to calculate the mean of row and to replace the missing.

I found answer there [Find and replace missing values with row mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812641/find-and-replace-missing-values-with-row-mean)

```
ind <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
df[ind] <- rowMeans(df[2:6],  na.rm = TRUE)[ind[,1]]
df
```